# howo to uninstall ubuntu9.10 and get rid of dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, grub, multi-boot

i installed ubuntu9.10 on my PC and works with XP very great. after install grub lead the system startup and i have to choose between ubuntu and xp.

right now,here's another version of ubuntu i want to install,so i have to get rid of grub and ubuntu9.10,i tried fdisk /mbr but id doesn't work.

so please anyone tell me how to get rid of grub and uninstall ubuntu9.10 ? thanks ahead.

Comment: @Jeff I would suggest migrating to askubuntu.com instead.

Answer (score 2):

Install the new version of Ubuntu (presumably 10.04, or 10.10, I'd recommend the former), on top of the existing Ubuntu 9.10 partitions. To do this, insert the boot disc for the new version, and install as normal until you reach disk partitioning. Select "manual", and remove, or "format" the partitions currently used by Ubuntu. Be careful not to remove or format your Windows partitions.

It's worth noting that, the practise of keeping a separate `/home` partition is useful in these situations. Furthermore, should you wish to temporarily keep 9.10 around, or you are happy to install the new Ubuntu side by side with the other operating systems, you will have no problem doing this. The most recent version of Ubuntu installed will be listed at the top of the boot menu.

Comment: The Ubuntu installer is smart enough to modify the current Grub setup (or completely overwrite it) so that all existing OS installations will show up in the Grub list.